# Javascript positioning not working in Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, webkit, position

I have a script going in Javascript, the purpose of which is to make an image stay centered in the window when the window is smaller than the image. It just moves the image to the left by half the difference between the image width and the window width so that the center of the image is always the center of the screen. When the window is not smaller than the image, this left offset is set to zero. And it works perfectly, if I'm in IE or Firefox. On the webkit browsers, it doesn't ever go to zero, creating an effect akin to `float:right` when the window is wider than the image. Here's the code:

```
setTimeout(slideImageWidth, 1);
function slideImageWidth() {
    var slideWidth = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("slide-image")).width,
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth,
        slide = document.getElementById("slide-image"),
        slideWidth = window.getComputedStyle(slide).width;
    if (windowWidth < (slideWidth.replace("px", "") + 1) && slide.style.display !== "none") {
        slide.style.left = ((((-slideWidth.replace("px", "") + windowWidth)) / 2) + "px");
    }
    else {
        slide.style.left = 0;
    setTimeout(slideImageWidth, 1);
};
```

I tried putting `slide.style.left = 0` before the if and just letting the loop take care of it in the next millisecond, but that didn't work either. I've also tried both placements with:

```
slide.style.left = "0px";
slide.style.left = 0 + "px";
slide.style.left = "0" + "px";
slide.style.left = 0px;
```

none of which worked in Chrome or Safari, but all but the last of which worked in Firefox and IE.

When I use `alert(slide.style.left)` when the window is wider than the image, a positive value is returned in Chrome and Safari, unlike the 0 from Firefox and IE, which tells me that the 0 value is never being written to `slide.style.left`. Yet, I know that I can modify `slide.style.left` because it still positions itself based on the equation.

Why does this code not work with the webkit browsers, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please use `setTimeout(slideImageWidth, 1);`

Comment: @AlienWebguy Done, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: It wasn't meant to change anything - just avoiding the use of `eval()` in the background which is a major code smell. You should adhere to this convention moving forward.

Comment: Oh, alright. Noted, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the things which I think are accidental typos:

1) Your code references something called "slide1Width", which is defined nowhere.
2) Your code references something called "slide1", which is defined nowhere.
3) You don't have the right number of close brackets, and the last bracket inexplicably has a semicolon after it.

Second, the most obvious error that isn't causing your specific problem:

```
(slideWidth.replace("px", "") + 1)
```

This expression is not what you want. If slideWidth is "440px", the replace() call gives you "440", and ("440" + 1) is the string "4441". I don't think that's what you mean to do here.

Third, and finally, what I believe is the cause of the actual bug you're asking about: timing. If you open up the dev tools and manually run slideImageWidth() on a wide window after it has loaded and failed to center itself, the image will in fact jump to the center, even on Chrome. Why doesn't it do it on page load? Here:

```
window.getComputedStyle(slide).width
```

That expression returns "0px" right when the page is first loaded. If you wait until the image is done loading, you'll be able to get an actual width for it, in which case you can do the calculations you want. (Or, presumably, you could set the width yourself via styling.) It seems that IE is getting the image loaded and flowed before running the script, whereas Chrome is not.

Comment: Surprisingly, that + 1 thing was my problem. FF and IE read it as 445, but Chrome and Safari took it as 4441. Problem 1 was a typo when I copied it over (thought I removed all of those 1s...). Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to use setTimeout instead of a resize event? What about something like this:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    setSlidePosition();    
};

function setSlidePosition() {
    var slideLeft = (document.getElementById("slide-image").style.left.indexOf('px') != -1 ) ? document.getElementById("slide-image").style.left : '0px';

    var numLeft = slideLeft.replace('px','');

    console.log(numLeft);

    var element = document.getElementById("slide-image")

    if(element.width > window.innerWidth) {
        var newLeft = (element.width - window.innerWidth) / 2 * -1 + "px";
        document.getElementById("slide-image").style.left = newLeft;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("slide-image").style.left = "0px";
    }
};

setSlidePosition();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4qomq7tb/45/

Seems to behave the same in chrome and FF at least. This doesn't specifically answer the question relating relating to your code, though :/